# I need to access folders from hard coded or desired path from Universal Windows app

Tags: win-universal-app

I am trying to create a universal windows app. I need to access folders from hard coded or desired path (eg. local folders related to some installers ). Is it possible to access all the paths, as we do in traditional c#? I tried to search about it in many forums- 
i can able to get only sample codes to access folders that are specified in the capabilities part. i.e. using KnownFolders class.

Exactly to say: **Is it possible to access folders without using windows.storage.Knownfolders class? I need an option similar to Directory.GetFiles(), where we can give our desired path as parameter** that we have in traditional c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Universal App runs inside a sandbox. By default, you can only access files in Application install directory or Application data locations. Other folders access is limited. You can just request additionnal capabilities to access KnownFolders. Please check the following documentation to obtain an overview on this topic.

[File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt188700.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your response Jean.

Comment: You're welcome. Can you please mark this question as answered if you don't need additional information ? Thx.

Comment: Sure, Is there any other options like adding an external c++/c# dll, to access required folders. is it possible to consume an external dll's in universal windows app? If any option is available- Please give me some reference. thx jean.

Comment: Adding a DLL won't help. The API are available to read anywhere the app has permission. The problem is that the app doesn't have permission to read or write arbitrary locations

Answer (score -1):

You can use Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker to access other folder